# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR even though my nginx config is configured

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, websocket, proxy

I've deployed an application on Digital Ocean with nginx. I've reverse proxyed my frontend port 8081 and made it ssl secure with Let's Encrypt. Now I need to secure my websocket server on port 8080 to prevent it from giving me this error "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

This is my current nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com; #managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite/fullchain.pem; #managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite/privkey.pem; #managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass ​http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
 
    location /websocket/ {
        proxy_pass ​http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }



    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; #managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; #managed by Certbot

}
```

Am I missing something? I've looked everywhere and what I can tell this setup should be correct?

Comment: On what URL you access the websocket from outside? And why don't you set the Host header too?

Comment: I can't acces websocket from any URL. I've tried to set the Host header for websocket by nothing happens. How do I setup so I can acces my websocket with url? https://mywebsite.com:8080 doesn't work.

Comment: *"`https://mywebsite.com:8080` doesn't work"* - that's expected and exactly that's why I asked how you try to access the websocket. You have explicitly configured nginx to proxy the websocket, so the correct URL to access it would be `https://mywebsite.com/websocket/`.

Comment: That URLgives me 502 Bad Gateway. I need to change my index.js so I can access it via that url https://mywebsite.com/websocket/?

Comment: Sorry, it should not be `https://...` but of course `wss://mywebsite.com/websocket/`

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx config seems correct, but you need to change your frontend app and configure it to properly append the urls.

I faced the same error when I was calling some backend APIs from my frontend on azure cloud. If you just want to enable websocket connection, you need to add the following in your web frontend config file.
In my case, I added it to my vue.config.js

```
`devServer: { webSocketServer: false,}`
```

This resolved my websocket error. I was facing the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR due to incorrect URL configuration as well. So you can have a look at your frontend fetcher functions where you are calling the APIs.

Feel free to comment if you don't resolve and we can have a more in-depth look!